How did a non-moderator single-handedly delete an answer?

Seems fine. Except… Journeyman Geek is neither a moderator nor was one 3 days ago. (He was a mod in the past, maybe that's related?)
Furthermore, the answer in question had a score of 14, so he shouldn't even have been able to vote to delete it. Note that the question was deleted (but like a year ago). So, why is this happening and could it please be fixed?

What post is that referring to? Had it already been flagged as something?

A deleted answer of mine…I doubt it was flagged on anything contributing to an auto nuke, no @W.O.

Perhaps we'd need to ascertain if it a glitch in a single site or network wide. Can you pinpoint the site?

This site @W.O.

@testing-for-ya clearly not automated, no flagged to death as then community bot would have deleted it, clearly not voted to deletion, question was deleted a while ago….

This way https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user

@AugustoVasques they can’t nuke a post or VTD something with a score of 14

I took a quick look and appear not to have voting to delete anything 3 days ago and most of these are lost souls. I generally don't vote to delete questions that are on topic, and you don't post off topic questions generally so.. I claim innocence here :D

@JourneymanGeek it’s the answer that was deleted by you…

I didn't delete any answer of yours (or anyone elses) 3 days ago.

I was going to say it could be the same bug as this, but that was marked status-completed a few years ago, so dunno.

I’m unsure if this is a valid concern, but if a answer was flagged as NAA or VLQ, then it entered to review queue. @JourneymanGeek voted to remove it as trusted user(not as mod). Other users was skipped the review leaving the answer in the queue with just one vote. Here’s where I’m uncertain, but I don't know of any documentation that specifies whether but if the system allows a Community user to promote a single removal vote stalled in the review queue, similar to how they handle stalled approval votes for edits.

This needs dates, as in date of the notification, date when the post was deleted, date when JG retired from modding Meta.

He didn't. Well, he did, but not 3 days ago, but further in the past, when he still was a moderator. What happened is that I undeleted the answer for science (moderators can undelete answers to deleted questions, which may or may not be a bug), and later that day the script that deletes answers to deleted questions ran. I'd expect that deletion to be attributed to the Community user, but apparently it doesn't.

I'm confused. The post you link in the text "undeleted the answer" is this bug report of yours on MSE. It has no deleted answers. It mentions you testing ("for science") by deleting an answer to this question, but the only deleted answer to that question was deleted by 3 community users (rene was not yet a mod, I don't think, but irrelevant), none of which include Journeyman Geek.

That first link is not really relevant, except that it mentions that moderators can undelete  answers to deleted questions, which is not obvious IMHO. I undeleted an answer in the question mentioned in that bug report, just like I did here. I haven't linked to the answer the OP is talking about.

Sorry, yes, I did mean to type "undeleted" in my comment. Unfortunately, that only added to the confusion here. Not linking to the answer that the question is asking about is... an odd decision, because it makes this entire answer extremely confusing. Even after spending a considerable amount of time following breadcrumbs, I still can't figure out what you're trying to describe; the evidence you've provided looks like it fails to substantiate your claims, and apparently that's because you're intentionally avoiding linking to the relevant context? Linking to unrelated posts makes it worse.

@CodyGray I hope the edit makes it clearer. I'll leave it to the OP to link to the answer or not.

Hmm, okay, yeah, that's probably better. Part of the reason I went looking is that I wanted to confirm that the system records the deletion users as the last humans who voted to delete the post, even though a bot was technically the last to cast a delete vote. This is how it works in cases where a moderator re-deletes an answer that was deleted via review and then undeleted by the author, for example. So that behavior may well be intentional, but I can't tell if the JG was the last or only user to delete the post, because the post was omitted. Still not sure why; deleted posts aren't secrets.

This is neither. I honestly don’t fully know why the post in question was deleted, it seems fine to me, but I figured it was deleted for some good reason, for some reason a mod dint want it to be seen. Linking to it and making the discussion about the post defeats the point of deleting it.

I think that saying "He deleted it a year ago while still being a moderator" would be even more clear. And the fact that after being re-deleted by automatic script it was attributed to him again also isn't a bug IMO, as the script didn't actually delete, just re-applied the state it should be in, kind of like reputation synch.

@ShadowWizard the bug is mainly that it says '3 days ago' - I agree with the script fixing my action, but the banner should say '1 year ago' or whenever the original deletion was done.

Ah, that is fair. Perhaps even worthy of a new bug report?
